# ValueError: RRULE UNTIL values must be specified in UTC when DTSTART is timezone-aware

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

I've been trying to parse recurrence rules using python's [dateutil rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) package

However, I am getting an odd error inconsistent with the way I understand recurrence rules

The error is

`ValueError: RRULE UNTIL values must be specified in UTC when DTSTART is timezone-aware`

The function I'm calling is

`recurrence = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181206T075959Z;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR"
rule = rrulestr(recurrence, dtstart=datetime.now())`

If the until is structured as `UNTIL=20181206T075959Z`, isn't that in UTC? Why would this error show up, and what is an appropriate solution? The thing is, this works with

`"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20191206T075959;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR"`, which I thought was not in UTC, because it was missing the 'Z'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a confusing error message because it is taken from the RFC spec but doesn't really explain the context.

The problem is that `dtstart` and `UNTIL` must both either be naive or timezone-aware, and the spec actually specifies that `UNTIL` has to be UTC specifically in that case.

To fix your code, you can just make `dtstart` timezone-aware:

```
from dateutil.tz import UTC
recurrence = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181206T075959Z;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR"
rule = rrulestr(recurrence, dtstart=datetime.now(UTC))
```

Feel free to report the confusing error message on [dateutil's issue tracker](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil).